# How to ignore entire unit test project using NUnit and ReSharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

I have a Visual Studio solution which contains a number of C# unit test projects based on NUnit. Our TeamCity environment selects the specific unit test DLLs to run. However, when running the unit tests in the solution locally using ReSharper, it runs everything. Is there a way of ignoring entire projects without having to put the `Ignore` attribute on every single test fixture?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. **Tag** all the tests in the project with a [[`Category`]](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.2.10) attribute.
2. [**Exclude** the specified category in Resharper's Unit Test settings](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Options__Tools__Unit_Testing.html)
   under *Skip tests from categories*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's fine, but I was kind of looking for something that is persisted to source control and ReSharper settings such as this one aren't. Before I posted the Question, I tried `Ignore` on the `SetUpFixture` class as all the `TestFixture` classes appear underneath it. But, this didn't work. Something like that would be ideal, though.

Comment: @Neo it's possible to [share Resharper settings](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp50/Configuring_ReSharper__Sharing_Configuration_Options.html), in which case you could add the settings file to source control, or are you saying this specific setting isn't shareable?

Comment: Was hoping for something I could use from NUnit at project level that ReSharper would respect. Putting ReSharper settings in source control is not something that would be acceptable in my team, but changing something in existing test code would be fine. Hmm..

Comment: I'm going to accept your solution as it answers the question, but I'm going to upvote yours _and_ **Cybermaxs - Betclic**'s as the other one is what I ended up having to do by just removing the test project from my test session. This solution doesn't help others as it can't be persisted to source control in my situation, but it at least removes the annoying big red error sign for me whilst I'm running unit tests locally. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Neo @stuartd  You can share any number of Resharper v9 settings files in a Visual Studio solution, so the settings file you need could include only this setting. Add it as a layer in the Resharper Settings layers. I try to put code templates in a separate file as well. There is also a local settings file in the VS Solution (`xxx.sln.DotSettings`) that tracks all the child files in the local layer - local users can edit this and then ignore it in source control locally.

Answer (score 9):

As alternative you could also add the Ignore flag to the project assembly which disabled all tests inside.

In AssemblyInfos.cs add:

```
[assembly: Ignore]
```

Comment: Just used this in a Net Core project with NUnit 3, and the required syntax now is `[assembly: Ignore("Broken")]`

Answer (score 3):

Resharper have the Unit Test Explorer Window, a structured list of your unit tests in your whole solution.

[image]

It's easy to select/unselect test/class/project to be compose any combination of tests in a test session. The group by combo could also be helpfull in your case.